# Remove all whitespaces in a file- Linux

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

How would I remove ALL whitespaces in a given file in Linux?

Comment: Within the file itself or in the file name?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Depending on your definition of whitespace, something like:

```
tr -d ' \t\n\r\f' <inputFile >outputFile
```

would do the trick.

Comment: +1 tr is "cheaper" than sed and you avoid invoking two programs

Comment: GNU tr has the class `[:space:]` for "all horizontal or vertical whitespace" (I assume "or" should be "and"). So `tr -d '[:space:]'` should do the trick too.

Comment: Also `\v` (vertical tab, which is also included in `[:space:]`).

Comment: I don't thing that `tr` works correctly on UTF-8 data, nor even ISO-8859-1, but only on mere ASCII.

Comment: @Darron- worked great for me, thnks. @tchrist- Interesting, I'll have to look into that

Comment: @tchrist: Some versions of tr will handle other character sets.  In non-ASCII cases the use of [:space:] is probably advised.

Comment: this answer if am not mistaken would also delete new line character which is not the objective here. tr -d ' \t\r\f' should instead be used which does not remove the new line character

Answer (score 16):

```
sed 's/\s//g' input.txt | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Can you please explain why `\s` in `'s/\s//g'` means whitespace?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

```
sed 's/\s//g'|tr -d '\n'
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have UTF-8 data, best do this:

```
perl -CS -pe 's/\p{Space}//g' < input > output
```