# How to count all spaces in a file in Unix

Tags: bash, gnu-coreutils

I want to count all the spaces from my file in Unix and I have tried the following command:

```
grep " " file1 | wc
```

It is giving me the following output:

```
3 6 34
```

There are three spaces in my file so is it accurate command and further more how can I filter this to get exactly the spaces so only '3' should come as output and also how can I remove it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109589/remove-all-whitespaces-in-a-file-linux

Comment: Did you try `wc --help`?  Did you look up wc documentation on the web?

Comment: Did you bother to say `man wc`?

Answer (score 19):

Use `grep` and `wc` in a way like this to count the occurrences of spaces:

```
grep -o ' ' | wc -l
```

`grep -o` will print every match in a separate line. The number of those lines can afterwards counted easily using `wc -l`

Answer (score 10):

Use `tr` to remove everything but the spaces, then `wc -c` to count the remaining (space) characters:

```
tr -cd ' ' <file1 | wc -c
```

Comment: Sweet and Simple!!

Answer (score 1):

This sed (stream editor) command will remove all the white space in a text file:

```
sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e 's/[ \t]*$//' yourFile
```